# pitchfork in plain TeX

Tags: symbols, plain-tex, amsfonts

I was asked the following question:

> How do I get get `\pitchfork` in plain TeX?

He tried `\input mssymb` and `\input amssymb` but neither works. More generally, is it possible to get ams symbols to work under plain TeX?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure,

```
\input amssym
$\pitchfork$
\bye
```

If one doesn't need all of the ~200 new control sequences, but only the additional fonts (ie. `\frak` for fraktur and `\Bbb` for blackboard bold), and a few extra symbols (see [amsfndoc](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsfonts/amsfndoc.pdf) [PDF], p. 18–19), one can just load the `amssym.def`.
(Note, however, that the `\pitchfork` symbol is not included in `amssym.def`.)

Comment: actually, `amssym.tex` loads `amssym.def`, so you need only the one line, `\input ammsym`.